# rails 3 issues with adding jquery javascript files or any other files to application.html.erb?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

This will sound like a stupid question for most but I'm really having problems with adding JavaScript files (such as jquery) to my application.html.erb, if I have the jquery first then the rails JavaScript doesn't work correctly. what's the best way to include all JavaScript files to the application.html.erb from my JavaScript folder?

Edit: how can I have Jquery and Prototype run side by said in my rails 3 application? what should my application.html.erb code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery and Prototype side-by-side, you should order your javascript include statements as follows:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "jquery.min", "jquery-ui.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

**Note:** After doing this, you will not be able to access any jQuery methods using `$(...)`. Instead, you'll need to use `jQuery(...)`

However, if you don't need Prototype, delete your `prototype.js` file and install the proper jQuery-specific `rails.js` file (the one that Rails uses by default is Prototype-specific). See https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs for instructions.

Comment: can you please include the code i should have? I want them to both run side by side, i have: `  <%= jQuery.noConflict(); %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min", "jquery-ui.min" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>` but it wont work, jquery wont work

Comment: The jQuery.noConflict() statement should be after you include jQuery, but before you include everything else.

Comment: Im so sorry for wasting your time, but im really having problems making it work. Can you just add code for what it should like? im relatively new to rails. when i put the statement i get an error saying : undefined local variable or method `jQuery'

Comment: Thank you @dmarkow I want them to run side by side, I tired your solution but it still wont work. its not recognizing the getting: **$(link).prev is not a function** in firebug. this is driving me mad.

Comment: That's because `$` is used by Prototype, and they can't both use it. Calling `jQuery.noConflict()` means that you have to replace `$` with `jQuery` when you want to use it. So try `jQuery(link).prev` instead.

Comment: thanks, that worked great! i have been in a computing degree for 4 years and i still dont know small things like that, i have a long road ahead of me!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create new project skip prototype with -J:

   rails new -J test -d mysql
2. Modify the Gemfile, add JQuery:

   gem 'jquery-rails'
3. Bundle update:

   bundle update rails
4. Generator the JQuery, --ui means withe JQuery UI:

   rails generate jquery:install --ui
5. Modify the config/application.rb:

   config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jquery-ui rails application)